# How can I have more than one array (multi arrays) in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
<?
//#
//#
$sale_products =
array(
    array("White_13", "50", "100")
    array("Black_31", "50", "100")
    array("Green_12", "50", "100")
);
foreach ($sale_products as $product) {
    echo '

        <div>
            <div>Product Name: '.$product[1].'</div>
            <div>Price: '.$product[2].'</div>
            <div>SALE PRICE: '.$product[3].'</div>
        </div>

    ';
}
//#
//#
?>
```

That is my code above. The `white_1` etc are the SKU for each product.

Comment: What is your exact problem. Are you getting a server error?

Comment: Yes `Unexpected T_ARRAY, expecting ')'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pop some commas on the end...

```
array(
    array("White_13", "50", "100"),
    array("Black_31", "50", "100"),
    array("Green_12", "50", "100")
);
```

And you are almost there... arrays are zero indexed

```
foreach ($sale_products as $product) {
    echo '

        <div>
            <div>Product Name: '.$product[0].'</div>
            <div>Price: '.$product[1].'</div>
            <div>SALE PRICE: '.$product[2].'</div>
        </div>

    ';
}
```

---

Also if you wanted to make it a bit more readible you could use associative arrays...

```
$sale_products = array(
    array("name" => "White_13", "price" => "50", "sale_price" => "100"),
    array("name" => "Black_31", "price" => "50", "sale_price" => "100"),
    array("name" => "Green_12", "price" => "50", "sale_price" => "100")
);
```

It makes it longer but the order of the properties no longer matters... Below is another way of outputting variables in strings. Change to double quotes and use the { }...

```
foreach ($sale_products as $product) {
    echo "

        <div>
            <div>Product Name: {$product["name"]}</div>
            <div>Price: {$product["price"]}</div>
            <div>SALE PRICE: {$product["sale_price"]}</div>
        </div>

    ";
}
```

Which approach is better is your call and depends on your use case.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about starting from 0

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid And the commas too

Comment: Was wondering how no one of the above noticed the missing comas ;)

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid, that working for you? If so don't be shy with marking this as the answer... ;-)

Comment: @StuartWakefield I was going to had to wait for time limit. +1 for showing the cleaner associate approach

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is correct except that array index in PHP start from `0` and not `1`. So the index of the produce name will be `0`, that of price is `1` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in your source. Note the commas after each subarray:

```
array(
    array("White_13", "50", "100"),
    array("Black_31", "50", "100"),
    array("Green_12", "50", "100"),
);
```

Yes, you can have unlimited depth of subarrays, and refer to it either how you're doing now, or through `$sale_products[0][1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an multidimensinal array. than you asses it with an extra parameter (don't know any better word)

You've got this code:

```
$sale_products =
array(
    array("White_13", "50", "100")
    array("Black_31", "50", "100")
    array("Green_12", "50", "100")
);
```

There is missing an comma after every new array. you must add them.

the output will be this of `$sale_products`:

```
$sale_products[0][0] = White_13
$sale_products[0][1] = 50
$sale_products[0][2] = 100
$sale_products[1][0] = Black_31
$sale_products[1][1] = 50
$sale_products[1][2] = 100
$sale_products[2][0] = Green_12
$sale_products[2][1] = 50
$sale_products[2][2] = 100
```

The first [] is the array selector (note, array's starts with an 0 instead of an 1 for the first entry).
The second [] is the selector for the array that you select in the first selector.

Hope this was clear :D

Answer (score -1):

```
<?
//#
//#
$sale_products =
array(
    array("White_13", "50", "100")
    array("Black_31", "50", "100")
    array("Green_12", "50", "100")
);
foreach ($sale_products as $product) {
    echo '

        <div>
            <div>Product Name: '.$product[0].'</div>
            <div>Price: '.$product[1].'</div>
            <div>SALE PRICE: '.$product[2].'</div>
        </div>

    ';
}
//#
//#
?>
```

Comment: Generates `unexpected T_ARRAY, expecting ')'` due to lack of comma